# Is docker count volume space into it's Data Space available?

Tags: docker

Which element of Docker are count the total amount of Data Space used by Docker :
images, volumes, containers, networks, ... ?

I have a space issue and the total space used by images + containers is very less than the Data Space Total I can see in Docker info.

Comment: On which OS are you working, on most linux servers you can just check with du -sh /var/lib/docker

Comment: I'am on CentOS, my problem is that the space I can see in "docker info" is not coherent with the size of my container, images and volume. My question to know if the volume space is a part of docker Data Space